# How to provide great UX in navigation from bird's eye view web-component to smaller web-component and vice-versa?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, interaction-design, web-app

I have a web application, let's call it "Molecule", that provides a bird's eye view over the status of several other web applications, let's call them "Atoms".

I want, somehow, to navigate from the "Molecule" to its "Atoms" and vice-versa (from "Atoms" to their aggregator "Molecule").

.

How can I provide a good navigation from an application to another, for my users, without breaking their experience?

Comment: Not an answer but have you looked at some prezi presentations which utilize the zoom in feature eg: http://prezi.com/nq67ujpgsr68/biogasol/

Comment: @MFrank2012: My bad. I've chosen a bad title. I'm actually not interested in a real zoom in/out. It's more in the sense of a broader app to a more particular app.

Comment: Do you have control over the "atoms"?

Comment: yes. I can alter the atoms as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to provide you with some inspiration that I hope will be useful for you. Firstly, highly respected designer [Brendan Dawes](http://www.brendandawes.com/) does a lot of this kind of thing with spokes and nodes to create alternative and explorative navigational systems. I have a feeling this is the kind of route that you are looking to go down. He has created [Doodlebuzz](http://www.doodlebuzz.com/), which although is not exactly what you would be trying to achieve, I do feel will add value to your ideation.

Secondly, take a look at the UK’s [NHS Health Explorer](http://www.nhs.uk/Search/Pages/HealthExplorer.aspx?q=Diabetes&qID=845#/tab~845~term~845~history~0), which allows you to search on a term and then surface interrelated information that can be, well, explored.

I hope you will keep us posted on your developments, these types of interfaces can be very exciting and rewarding.

Comment: Although, with DoodleBuzz, it was way too easy for me to do things like create completely incomprehensible doodles...I actually did it by accident the first time by drawing a circle -_-